# What does it mean in JavaScript "bool && action()"?

Tags: javascript

How should we interpret the following code in JavaScript:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    tests[i] && (buffer[i] = getPlaceholder(i));/* how this line interpreted */
```

I see that somewhere but I don't know what the inner code mean.

Comment: Please change your title to something meaningful or this question will get destroyed by downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tests[i] && (buffer[i] = getPlaceholder(i));
```

The code is using [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()). First the statement before `&&` - `tests[i]` is executed and if that is truthy then only the statement after `&&` - `(buffer[i] = getPlaceholder(i))` is executed.

The code is equivalent as follow

```
if (test[i]) {
    buffer[i] = getPlaceholder(i);
}
```